# Usage of COUNT (Distinct column_name)

Tags: php, mysqli, count, distinct

This might be a basic question but I have been struggling to find the correct usage of COUNT (distinct) function . Here's is what I want to do: I want to find the unique values in column `id_u`.

What I have written is

```
$result2=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_u) FROM openevaluation WHERE id_by=1");
$et2= mysqli_num_rows($result2);
echo "Count: ". $et2. "<br>" ;
```

Comment: Do you want to know the unique values or just how many unique values are present?

Comment: Adding to RST's question, getting the number of rows should give you a result of one when using count as you're currently doing.  If you want the count, don't use the mysqli_num_rows() function.  If you want the distinct id_u values remove the count() function from your query.

Comment: @RST  How many unique values are present

Comment: @alaric Thank you :)
Resolved. If you write down an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: There may be a way of accepting a comment as a solution though I'm not sure, in any event I've added an answer for the simplicity of anyone searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the number of rows should give you a result of one when using count as you're currently doing. If you want the count, don't use the mysqli_num_rows() function. If you want the distinct id_u values remove the count() function from your query.